# Treelike component in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

Is there any ways to generate treelike structure in JasperReport? If it exists, it would be awesome, otherwise it would be a great headache

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you want to produce?

If you have known number of "levels" you could make groups for each of these levels and print "level" name in header of the group (and hide details band) and thus simulating treelike structure.